# Price input in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently switched to Rails4 and i'm. not. getting. things. to. work...

**`ANSWER: As Aman remembered me, in Rails 4 we have to filter attributes in the Controller.`**

I want to add Pricing to my Listings Scaffold.

1.) Generate a Migration

```
rails g migration AddPriceToListings price:decimal
```

2.) Edit the migration:

```
add_column :listings, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

3.) Add Input to my Form

```
<!-- Price Field -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Price</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.input :price, :placeholder => "0.00", label: false %>
  </div>
</div>
```

4.) On the Showpage

```
<%= number_to_currency(@listing.price, :unit => "$") %>
```

But on my Shopage there is nothing. The prices doesn't get displayed. It don't even show up in the Database.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It looks fine when I tried this.

Comment: Then you are not on Rails 4, as Aman Answered (and i forgot to) you have to filter your attributes inside the Listings Controller. :)

Comment: My bad I haven't switched to Rails 4.;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails4, you have to permit parameters if you are mass assignining via form:

Make sure Attributes are filtered inside listings_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @listing = Listing.create(listing_params)
  ...
end
...
private
  def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:price, :name) #name can be replaced by other parameters received via form.
  end
```

Comment: I WAS LITERALLY thinking and over-thinking this for a good half hour, and forgot totally the new attribute filtering :) Thanks a lot aman !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the `:decimal` in migration file

Edit the migration again by this

```
add_column :listings, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```